# RewriteRule URL to Query Encoding Plus(+)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Im using this RewriteRule to navigate `host.com/edit/somenicepage` to `host.com/edit.php?page=somenicepage` and this works fine.

```
RewriteRule (.*edit)/(.*)$ $1.php?page=$2 [QSA,END]
```

Normally if query sent as `host.com/test.php/hey=a%2Bb` value of the `hey` becomes `a+b`. But in this case for the request `host.com/edit/a%2Bb` the value of the `page` parameter becomes `a b`. I think because server decodes the URL first then writes this part as query then it decodes it again. So `a%2Bb` becomes `a+b` then `a b` (for query string spaces are encoded as +).

So how can I encode it as query string before rewriting?

Answer (score 1):

So the solution is using [B flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) on the RewriteRule. I changed the line to this. `RewriteRule (.*edit)/(.*)$ $1.php?page=$2 [B,QSA,END]`

But this also encodes the part before the '.php' (group $1). To prevent that I changed the rule to this `RewriteRule ^path/edit/(.*)$ /path/edit.php?page=$1 [B,QSA,END]`

Comment: "But this also encodes the part before the '.php'" - maybe limiting the characters that are escaped would workaround this issue? eg. `[B=+,QSA,END]` (requires Apache 2.4.26).